# SetSpan multiple times

Tags: android

I'm trying to set two spans on a spannable string, but the only one showing up is the latter one. i was expecting the first one to show up due to index problems, but instead the second one did. Does the second set span override the first one? I saw samples that they claim works, not sure why mine doesn't. Here's the snippet. Thanks!

```
String targetStr = "target1";
String targetStr2 = "target2";
String str = "Lorem ipsum target1 dolor target2 sit amet";
Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img);
icon.setBounds(0, 0, textView.getLineHeight(), textView.getLineHeight());
ImageSpan is = new ImageSpan(icon);
SpannableString text = new SpannableString(str);
int indOf = str.indexOf(targetStr);
int lenOf = targetStr.length();
text.setSpan(is, indOf, indOf + lenOf, 0);
int indOf1 = str.indexOf(targetStr2);
int lenOf1 = targetStr2.length();
text.setSpan(is, indOf1, indOf1 + lenOf1, 0);
textView.setText(text);
```

Answer:
LOL. So stupid. The answer was that you can only use an ImageSpan once, so i had to set another image span, even if it has the same value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LOL. So stupid. The answer was that you can only use an ImageSpan once, so i had to set another image span, even if it has the same value.

Comment: Thank you.. I spent to much time on this ;(

Comment: Thanks. I had instantiated a new span _outside_ of a `for` loop and was trying to set it to a different substring on each iteration, and I was so confused as to why the span was only being applied to the final iterated substring. Once I moved the span instantiation _inside_ of the `for` loop, it worked like a charm.